# python script, downloading html content instead of streaming video

Tags: python, html, video, streaming

I'm kind of new to python (and programming things), so I'm trying to practise different kind of exercises. One of them is to download a streaming video using a script (python3). The problem is that I do not download the video but the html content of the webpage... Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong ?

Here is my code :

```
import Mail
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib
import time
import requests

mail = Mail.Mail()

def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                # f.flush() commented by recommendation from J.F.Sebastian
    return local_filename


if __name__ == '__main__':

    url = 'https://youtu.be/xKsEKgAF7kE'


filename = download_file(url)
print(filename, " has been downloaded.")
```

Do not pay attention to rubbish like mail things, this is a class I created for a further usage, or useless imports : my first looked different at first, I wasn't using requests lib, and my code was different but the result is the same (this code comes from other stackoverflow topic).

Thank you a lot for trying to help ! :)

Comment: You should take a look at YouTube DL its a Python project to do just this thing. It does also work on other sites that are not YouTube. https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl

Comment: Also a side note. I think you are breaking YouTubes terms of service by scraping. They have an API they would rather you use.

Comment: Thank you for comment, I'm aware that such tools already exist, this is practical training exercise. I'll later try to automatically download video (when a new episode of my fav serie is realeased for example). Here, the example is a youtube url, but it could be something else.

Comment: I understand that you are doing this for learning. I'm suggesting that you read over there code to see how they have pulled down the video files.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow and let you know the benefits I took from your link ! Thank you a lot

Comment: Apparently, it is using YT API :/

Comment: It would need to because scraping YT breaks there terms of service agreement. They hold the right to outright block you from being able to access YT if you do it. In some cases it can be a crime to scrape a website, so always use the API or read the terms of service before scraping.

Answer (score 0):

**It's better to use pytube module and look inside of it. So I thing this may help you **

```
    from pytube import YouTube
from pprint import pprint

yt = YouTube("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y")


print(yt.get_videos())


# The filename is automatically generated based on the video title.  You
# can override this by manually setting the filename.

# view the auto generated filename:
print(yt.filename)

# Pulp Fiction - Dancing Scene [HD]

# set the filename:
yt.set_filename('Enything')

# You can also filter the criteria by filetype.
print(yt.filter('flv'))

print(yt.filter(resolution='480p'))

video = yt.get('mp4', '720p')

# NOTE: get() can only be used if and only if one object matches your       criteria.
# for example:

print(yt.videos)

#[<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 144p>,
# <Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 240p>,
# <Video: Sorenson H.263 (.flv) - 240p>,
# <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 360p>,
# <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 480p>,
# <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 360p>,
# <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 720p>,
# <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 360p>,
# <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 480p>]

# Since we have two H.264 (.mp4) available to us... now if we try to call get()
# on mp4...

video = yt.get('mp4')
# MultipleObjectsReturned: 2 videos met criteria.

# In this case, we'll need to specify both the codec (mp4) and resolution
# (either 360p or 720p).

# Okay, let's download it! (a destination directory is required)
video.download('/tmp/')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I've seen this module for youtube videos, I'll check if it's using YT api or if I can use for any kind of video. I'll check tomorrow and let you know ;)

Comment: Apparently, it is using YT api, so I can't do much. their download method is similar as my first one, so this is a good point ^^. I'll now focus on trying to find the URL of the media content diplayed on the webpage.

Comment: Good luck ! I'm also tring to do that and check other ways to do that using YT api ... (youtube developers uses python for devolop it so keep it in you're mind :) )

Comment: Do not hesitate to update your results if you want to ! I'll share mine when they will be interesting !